# What is wrong with my insert query in linq c#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i have a table with a name

```
logtbl(logid int, emplid int, logdate date, description varchar(50), logtime time(7), logdatetime datetime)
```

Here is my code:

```
public void savelogs(int idemp, DateTime logdate, string logname, TimeSpan logtimes, DateTime timedate)
{
    logtbl log = new logtbl()
    {
        emplid = idemp,
        datelog = logdate,
        description = logname,
        timelog = logtimes,
        logdatetime = timedate
    };
    dbko.logtbls.InsertOnSubmit(log);
    dbko.SubmitChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Log save successfully;");
}
```

And i call it like this:
a stands for integer
dtdate and dttime stands for datetimepicker

```
savelogs(a, dtdate.Value.ToShortDateString, cmbstatus.Text, dttime.Value.ToShortTimeString, dtdate.Value.ToShortDateString);
```

the error is in this line of code.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: do you have a full error description? maybe some of your fields have not been mapped correctly, for example your class has datelog and timelog fields, but table has logdate and logtime columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are now giving a methodgroup as argument while the method is expecting a datetime. The correct call to the method should be the following:

```
savelogs(a, dtdate.Value, cmbstatus.Text, dttime.Value, dtdate.Value);
```

This means that you will need to remove the `ToShortDate` method from the call and place it inside the method or change the arguments for your method to strings instead of `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`